# How to get the default resx file from a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

For example I have got these files:

> Form1.Designer.cs
>
> Form1.en-US.resx
>
> Form1.resx

I want to access the Form1.resx file.
This is what I tried, but it returns me - based on the language of the operating system - the resx file. But I always want to have that form1.resx file no matter the language of the operating system.

```
ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(Form1)); 
ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("TranslatedText.Form1",typeof(Form1).Assembly);
```

Do I overlook something?

Comment: Hard to make sense of the question.  The .resx file exists only on your machine, you don't deploy it to the user's machine.  So you can't "access" it.  ResourceManager.GetString() takes CultureInfo as an argument.

Comment: @HansPassant That could make sense, but in the form1.resx are also other declarations of other things like the name of the form. So the form1.resx has to be deployed on the user's machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found myself an answer.

This is what I did, and it works :)

```
ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
```

Gets the resources of the Form1 class.

```
string defaultCultureValue = rm.GetString("label1.Text", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(""));
```

This will try to get a specific culture, which there is't, so it will get the created default culture which is the Form1.resx file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can always access it like a class.

```
<Name of resx file>.<name of the key added>
```

eg: If you a resource file called **Resource1** and a string value **testkey**, then this can be accessed as

```
Resource1.testkey
```

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that might help you. It has code to retrieve a value from resource files yb giving in the location of the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that it is nested under my Form1.cs class. And when I'm trying to get the Form1.resx file I can't. Like this: TranslatedText.Form1.Form1.resx < that does not work

Comment: @Castrovalva : have added a link which has steps to retrieve resource file values.