# How to compare original this.text from resource file to an overwritten text

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, resx

I have a windows form. Where the title will be overwritten every time a piece of code is hit.
The title will be by default in resx file of the form until it is overwritten.

Form1.resX

```
 <data name="$this.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Report</value>
  </data>
```

Form2.cs

```
public void Report2()
{
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Text="Report2"
//Some code
}

public void Report3()
{
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Text="Report3"
//Some code
}
```

Here the `this.Text` gets overwritten when `Report2()` and `Report3()` executes

In Form1.cs

```
private void Report_ColumnClick(Object eventSender, ColumnClickEventArgs eventArgs)
{
if(this.Text!="Report")
{
//Some code
}
}
```

So in Form1.cs i am hard coding the resx original value to compare with an overwritten value.
Is there anyway i can do it dynamically instead of hard coding.

Comment: If you are looking get get values from your Resources you can write code like 
Properties.Resources.<YourReosurceName>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191911/how-to-get-the-default-resx-file-from-a-form) is the same as yours?

According to that post it should be as simple as:

```
ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
string formText = rm.GetString("Form1.Text");
```

***OR:***

If that doesn't work you can try reading the information from the manifest embedded in the assembly.

Get the embedded resource names using reflection `typeof(Form1).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();` this will give you a list on names if there are any.

use the correct name to extract the embedded stream.

```
var resourceStream = typeof(Form1).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Your_NamesPace_Here.Form1.resources");
using (System.Resources.ResourceReader resReader = new ResourceReader(resourceStream))
{
  var dictEnumerator = resReader.GetEnumerator();
  while (dictEnumerator.MoveNext())
  {
    var ent = dictEnumerator.Entry;
    //ent will be a key:value pair, so use it like this                     
    if (ent.Key as string  == "$this.Text")
    {
      string originalFormName = ent.Value as string;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works and exactly what i was looking for. Is there any other way like enum or something that can bifurcate?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You will have to decide what the bifurcation point is. Build a switch or enum to indicate what branch to go down.

Comment: When the text gets overwritten with Report2 or Report3. I will have to bifurcate with that. Based on what is in ```this.text```